# React Native Video Fullscreen

Tags: react-native, expo

Hi i am new to react and i have a problem

I am building an app with over 250+ video's
i searched the internet and came across 3 solutions

1. react video player
2. expo av
3. webview

i tried them all and number 1 and 2 didn't work for me because

1. react video player is not working in my because i use expo and dont want to sepperate ios and android
2. expo av don't assist vimeo video's

so i tried webview and it works fantastic except for one thing, the fulsscreen button is so small and sometimes doesn't react.

```
<WebView
          allowsFullscreenVideo
          scrollEnabled={false}
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', flex: 1}}
          allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
          source={{
            html: `
              <html>
                <body>
                  <div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
                  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/552860378?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen;" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="PBS1 - Leven uit verlossing - BOEKVERSLAG"></iframe>
                  </div>
                  <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
                </body>
              </html>
            `,
          }}
        />
```

how can i solve this problem? or is there anyway to do it with another technology.
i am considering putting al the video's in a database so i can do it with expo av but is this a good option?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific property to do so but you can achieve it using ***`injectedJavaScript`***

You can add your JS script to add custom style to enlarge button and inject in WebView